# Javascript - How to access object outside success block

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, object

I need to access an object after AJAX has modified but when I try to print it it shows an empty value

How can I fix this?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   var arrayLength = whatever...;
   var myArray = [];

   for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

       $.ajax({
           myArray: myArray,
           type: 'GET',
           dataType: 'jsonp',
           data: {},
           url: "https://api....",
           error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               console.log(jqXHR)
           },
           success: function (response) {
               var name = response.data.name;
               var url = response.data.url;
               for(var x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
                   var pin = {name: name, url:url};
                   myArray.push(pin);
               }
           },
           async: false
       });
   }

   // I want to print myArray here
});
```

Comment: What is `allPins` push `pin` in `myArray` not in `allPins` and remove `myArray: myArray,`

Comment: how is myArray being used? doesn't look like its been accessed at all

Comment: @RobH, He's using `async: false`, so I'm not sure that linked page is relevant.

Comment: What's the intended effect of adding that "myArray" property to the `$.ajax()` parameter object?

Comment: @ikegami - ah yes, knee-jerk from me. Didn't see that lurking at the bottom!

Comment: are you sure that you are reaching the success callback?  place breakpoint or console.log at ' myArray.push(pin);'

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   var arrayLength = whatever...;
   var myArray = [];

   for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

       $.ajax({
           //myArray: myArray,
           type: 'GET',
           dataType: 'jsonp',
           data: {},
           url: "https://api....",
           error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               console.log(jqXHR)
           },
           success: function (response) {
               var name = response.data.name;
               var url = response.data.url;
               for(var x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
                   var pin = {name: name, url:url};
                   //allPins.push(pin);
                   myArray.push(pin);
               }
           },
           async: false
       });
   }

   // I want to print myArray here
});
```

Comment: wouldn't 'myArray' still not be populated at that point with async: true?

Comment: Your change from `async: false` to `async: true` will cause the printing to be reached too soon.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo! And when I change async: false to async: true it still shows me an empty array